# Graph Database Nebula Graph insert record failed but query regular

Tags: graph-databases, nebula-graph

I'm using the graph database [Nebula Graph](https://github.com/vesoft-inc/nebula) and encounter that query is regular but always fails when I want to insert records. Here are some logs:

```sh
root@f10cace4998c logs]# tail -f nebula-graphd.f10cace4998c.root.log.ERROR.20191213-114343.1 
E1216 02:14:24.674852    14 StorageClient.inl:102] Request to [172.28.1.2:44500] failed: N6apache6thrift9transport19TTransportExceptionE: AsyncSocketException: write timed out during connection, type = Timed out
E1216 02:18:16.785874    14 StorageClient.inl:102] Request to [172.28.1.2:44500] failed: N6apache6thrift9transport19TTransportExceptionE: AsyncSocketException: write timed out during connection, type = Timed out
E1216 02:18:20.375427    16 StorageClient.inl:102] Request to [172.28.1.2:44500] failed: N6apache6thrift9transport19TTransportExceptionE: AsyncSocketException: write timed out during connection, type = Timed out
E1216 02:32:23.215456    15 StorageClient.inl:102] Request to [172.28.1.2:44500] failed: N6apache6thrift9transport19TTransportExceptionE: AsyncSocketException: write timed out during connection, type = Timed out
```

Answer (score 1):

After I check myself, I've found that my nebula stroage service had been destroyed unexpectly, which makes the record inserting fail. Because I use the nebula in docker, so I found this by command this:

```sh
docker ps | grep -e nebula
```

```sh
5120cb3ae046        vesoft/nebula-storaged:nightly   "./bin/nebula-storag…"   12 days ago         Up 30 hours (healthy)   12000/tcp, 12002/tcp, 44500-44501/tcp                    scripts_storaged_1
f10cace4998c        vesoft/nebula-graphd:nightly     "./bin/nebula-graphd…"   12 days ago         Up 30 hours (healthy)   3369/tcp, 13000/tcp, 13002/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3699->3699/tcp   scripts_graphd_1
68449fbc74d6        vesoft/nebula-metad:nightly      "./bin/nebula-metad …"   12 days ago         Up 30 hours (healthy)   11000/tcp, 11002/tcp, 45500-45501/tcp                    scripts_metad_1
```

Gennerally, nebula will have three server running: storage, meta, graphd. It will go wrong when any one of them stops.

As for the destroying of the nebula storage. I don't have any idea and need to find more details about that.